# Adding existing models to many-to-many relationship with Entity Framework 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I have a table, Modules and a table Students, that have a many-to-many relationship through a pivot table ModuleStudents. I am trying to add students to a module but encounter an error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'
>   occurred in TestingEF.exe
>
> Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.

```
SchoolContext context = new SchoolContext();

List<Module> modules = context.Modules.ToList();
Student student = context.Students.Single(s => s.MatriculationNumber == 40122047);

foreach (Module module in modules)
{
    module.Students.Add(student);
}

context.SaveChanges();
```

What am I doing wrong here? I am fetching all the modules in the database and returning them as a list which I am then iterating over and trying to add a student to? I don't understand why I am receiving a System.NullReferenceException

Contents of the output from the excpetion: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/bb719a215ded5518af46

I am using Code First for this project (a learning exercise using a Console Solution).

Module class:

```
class Module
{
    public int ModuleID { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Course Course { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

Student class:

```
class Student
{
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public int MatriculationNumber { get; set; }
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }

    public virtual Course Course { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Module> Modules { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Which part is it exactly that is throwing the exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your Module class creating the Students list in the default constructor, like this:

```
class Module
{
    public Module()
    {
        this.Students = new List<Student>();
    }

    public int ModuleID { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Course Course { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This works, but shouldn't EF determine the type and create a new instance of List<Student> Students itself without it having to be declared in the constructor?

Comment: Thats a good question. Well we use EF 6.1 (which I recommend you to use it too if you can) and the behavior is the same. Maybe there is a good reason for the EF behave like this. Next time I work with that I will try to think about it.

Answer (score 1):

A call stack for the exception would be nice but if I had to make a wild guess, I would say that `Students` is `null` in this line `module.Students.Add(student);`. Are you using code first to build your models? If so then you can initialize `Students` in `Module's` constructor; like so:

```
public Module
{
    Students = new List<Student>();
}
```

Comment: I am using Code First for this approach. I have included a link above to the output.

Comment: It appears that Student is in fact null. If I have defined a property public virtual ICollection<Student> Students in my Module.cs class should that not be set to a List<Student> by EF? I created a constructor for the Module.cs class and assigned Student = new List<Student>(); and there are no errors now, but why?

Comment: from my observations,EF doesn't initialize collections by default so you'll have to initialize those yourself in the constructor.